# Angular.js not displaying array of objects retrieved from $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular.js and I am trying to understand how to use the $http functions like `$http.get` and `$http.post`.

I have a very simple app retrieving messages from a MySQL database through a Java rest service. The data returned looks like:

```
[
  {id:1, content:"Hello World!"}, 
  {id:2, content:"Testing 1, 2, 3..."}, 
  {id:3, content:"I am from the database"}
]
```

I am attempting to list them using ng-repeat like so:

```
<div ng-controller="MessageController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="m in messages">{{m.content}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then my controller looks like so:

```
function MessageController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getAll = function(callback) {
    $http.get('/messages').success(function(response) { callback(response); });
  }

  $scope.messages = $scope.getAll(function(data) { return JSON.stringify(data); });
}
```

I see the call is properly returning an array of message objects and I can print them to the console from within the callback function but for some reason they are not being displayed in the `ng-repeat`. I was able to get this to work when I was manually creating a list of messages, but when I introduced the `$http.get` piece, it stopped working.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** I am using angular.js version 1.2.19

Comment: Did you try `console.log`-ing the response? Usually your data is on the `data` property of the `response` object in the `$http` callback. Try changing `callback(response)` to `callback(response.data)`

Comment: @KhalilRavanna I added a log statement in the get function `...console.log(response); callback(response);...` and the JSON array I mentioned above is printed. When I tried `response.data` it printed `undefined`.

Comment: Thought it would be something simple like that. Looks like the answers below have it though. It's not updating because your function `$scope.getAll` doesn't actually return anything. You can either have that $scope method update $scope.messages itself or you can make `$scope.getAll` return `$http.get` and then inside of the success callback return `callback(response)`. That way your `$scope.getAll` method returns a promise that will resolve with your evaluated callback. I believe that works. `$resource` also works but I abhor that service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per AngularJS version 1.2, arrays are not unwrapped anymore (by default) from a Promise (see [migration notes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templates-no-longer-automatically-unwrap-promises)). I've seen it working still with `Objects`, but according to the documentation you should not rely on that either.

Instead, you should use [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) for this. Resources don't return Promises anymore, but 'future' objects. In practice that means an empty object or array depending on the REST call, which fills itself once the REST call resolves ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/8zVxH/1/)).

In your case it would be something like the following (pseudo):

```
function MessageController($scope, $resource) {
    var resource = $resource('/messages');
    $scope.messages = resource.query(function (data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data); // is this really necessary, though?
    });
    // $scope.messages = resource.query(); // should be enough
}
```

You will need the ngResource module dependency for that (don't forget to include angular-resource.js in your index.html):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
```

Comment: I was able to get it working once I added the `ngResource` piece. Also, you were right `JSON.stringify(data);` was not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You should assign a value to the $scope.messages variable inside the the success function from the $get http call. Something like this: (see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H54esqDFWTyMzg6S4tDk?p=preview))

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MessageController', function($scope, $http) {


  $scope.getAll = function() {
    $http.get('data.json').success(function(response) {
      $scope.messages = response;
    });
  }

  $scope.getAll();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're code isn't working but the following should work. The `$scope` is updated in the callback.

```
function MessageController($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getAll = function(callback) {
    $http.get('/messages').success(function(response) { callback(response); });
  }

  $scope.getAll(function(data) { $scope.messages = JSON.stringify(data); });
}
```

Comment: Pretty obvious why his code does not work. `$scope.getAll` does not return anything, so regardless of what's happening inside of it `$scope.messages` will be `undefined`. The data returned by the callback is only accessible inside the scope of the caller (the `success` method of `$http`). And the caller does nothing with it. It would be also useless if `success` would return the result because it would return it _after_ the async `$http` call.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve with:

- After the call, initializing a variable

  ```
  $scope.myRender = false;
  ```
- Then do the call... after and success:

  ```
  $scope.myRender = true;
  ```

and the html use `ng-if="myRender" ng-model="myModel"`

Good luck!