# Ng-repeat is not displaying json data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

thanks advance for any support. So I have a factory that uses a post to get some data from a C# method. That all seems to be working as I can see the data in the console log when it gets returned. However, when I get the data, I can't seem to get it to display properly using ng-repeat.

I've tried a couple different ways of nesting ng-repeats and still no luck. So now I'm thinking I may have not passed the data from the call properly or my scope is off. I've also tried passing data.d to hangar.ships instead of just data. Still pretty new to angular so in any help to point me int he right direction is greatly appreciated.

app code:

```
var app = angular.module('shipSelection', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
app.controller('ShipController', function ($scope, ShipService) {
    var hangar = this;
    hangar.ships = [];

var handleSuccess = function (data, status) {
    hangar.ships = data;

    console.log(hangar.ships);
};

ShipService.getShips().success(handleSuccess); 

});

app.factory('ShipService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getShips: function () {
            return $http({
                url: '/ceresdynamics/loadout.aspx/getships',
                method: "post",
                data: {},
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Markup:

```
<div class ="col-lg-12" ng-controller="ShipController as hangar" > 
    <div class =" row">
        <div class="col-lg-4" ><input ng-model="query" type="text"placeholder="Filter by" autofocus> </div>
    </div><br />
        <div class="row"> 
            <div ng-repeat="ship in hangar.ships | filter:query | orderBy:'name'">              
             <div class="col-lg-4">    
                <div class="panel panel-default">        
                    <div>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item" >
                               <p><strong>ID:</strong> {{ ship.ShipID }} <strong>NAME:</strong> {{ ship.Name }}</p>
                                           <img ng-src="{{ship.ImageFileName}}" width="100%" />      
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>                                              
                </div><!--panel-->
              </div> <!--ng-repeat-->
            </div>  
       </div> 
  </div> <!--ng-controller-->
```

JSON returned from the post(From the console.log(hangar.ships):

```
Object
d: "[{"ShipID":"RDJ4312","Name":"Relentless","ImageFileName":"Ship2.png"},{"ShipID":"ZLH7754","Name":"Hercules","ImageFileName":"Ship3.png"},{"ShipID":"FER9423","Name":"Illiad","ImageFileName":"Ship4.png"}]"
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per AngularJS version 1.2, arrays are not unwrapped anymore (by default) from a Promise (see migration notes). I've seen it working still with Objects, but according to the documentation you should not rely on that either.

Please see this answer [Angular.js not displaying array of objects retrieved from $http.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891995/angular-js-not-displaying-array-of-objects-retrieved-from-http-get)

What happens if you add JSON.parse(data);

If this works you should add some checks in and perhaps migrate that logic to the service.  Or use $resource per the other answer.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fa6e411da26824a5bae55f37ce7dbb859653276d

Comment: Thank you! json.parse did the trick, I thought I had tried that earlier but I've mucked around with so many things on this I can't remember which combination of code I did that with. Side note: I actually had to do json.parse(data.d) as data.d is the name the array it returns. Thanks again!